# GCC not working but G++ does

Tags: c, gcc, debian

I am trying to run some programs on a BeagleBone Black on the 'out of the box' operating system but I keep getting issues when compiling with gcc. This is best illustrated when trying to compile a simple hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 printf("Hello World\n");
 return 0;
}
```

The output from compiling and running this is:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ g++ helloworld.c -o test
debian@beaglebone:~$ ./test
Hello World
debian@beaglebone:~$ gcc helloworld.c -o test
debian@beaglebone:~$ ./test
./test: line 27: typedef: command not found
./test: line 36: typedef: command not found
./test: line 37: typedef: command not found
./test: line 38: typedef: command not found
./test: line 39: typedef: command not found
./test: line 42: typedef: command not found
./test: line 43: typedef: command not found
./test: line 44: typedef: command not found
./test: line 45: typedef: command not found
./test: line 46: typedef: command not found
./test: line 47: typedef: command not found
./test: line 52: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 53: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 61: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 62: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 68: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 69: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 70: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 71: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 72: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 73: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 74: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 75: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 76: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 77: __extension__: command not found
./test: line 78: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./test: line 78: `__extension__ typedef struct { int __val[2]; } __fsid_t;'
debian@beaglebone:~$
```

My gcc and g++ versions are:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

debian@beaglebone:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Has anyone come across this problem before? I've had a look around but none of the fixes seem applicable. Thanks in Advance.

edit: output of `gcc -v helloworld.c -o outputFile`

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ gcc -v helloworld.c -o outputFile
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' 'outputFile' '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf helloworld.c -o outputFile -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -mtls-dialect=gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 /usr/include
End of search list.
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/../../../:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/lib/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' 'outputFile' '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
```

Comment: Did you inspect the content of the output file? Also, did you check whether *gcc* is a symlink or a text file (a script faking *gcc*'s behavior)?.

Comment: Are you using bash? Can you do a `type gcc` to see how the shell is interpreting it?

Comment: Try calling your executable something other than `test`

Comment: so. which gcc returns /usr/bin/gcc.

Comment: Ok, what does `file /usr/bin/gcc` tell you? And how did you install *gcc*, also is this Ubuntu?

Comment: /usr/bin/gcc does nothing.

Comment: looking at the output file it shows stuff like 
# 1 "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 389 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 29 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4

Comment: And `echo $PATH`? What does it output?

Comment: Type this: `unalias gcc` and try again.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally throw in a `-E` to the gcc options?

Comment: "echo $PATH" returns "
/home/debian/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
"

Comment: @DylanKirkby Why on earth will that help? It's pretty clear that `-E` *gcc* option is causing this problem.

Comment: unalias gcc gives '-bash: unalias: gcc: not found'

Comment: Sorry: `unalias -a gcc`

Comment: it accepts that, but still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Can you post the output of `gcc -v helloworld.c -o test`?

Comment: @user3793489, what is ending up in file `./test` when you run `gcc` is the preprocessed source, as if you had supplied the `-E` option on the command line.  That is not `gcc`'s normal behavior, and the comments have been aimed at some plausible reasons why you might get that behavior without explicitly specifying `-E`.  Since that's not panning out, you should consider inquiring on a support forum specific to BeagleBone.

Comment: the first lines of the output are 
`# 1 "helloworld.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "helloworld.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 323 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/predefs.h" 1 3 4
# 324 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 356 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4`

Comment: the output of `gcc -v helloworld.c -o test` is too long to post, anything you are looking for in particular?

Comment: Output of `gcc -v helloworld.c -o test` does include:

`COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' 'test' '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'` which does suggest -E could be a problem

Comment: sorry, added now, was meaning too long as a comment

Comment: Try typing `/usr/bin/gcc` instead of `gcc`.  Also try `g++ -x c` (which should be exactly equivalent to `gcc` if your file extension is `.c`)

Comment: also try issuing the command `hash -r` and then do the gcc command again

Comment: `/usr/bin/gcc` shows no change. whilst `g++ -x c` does work, like g++ does. 

`hash -r` did not change anything

Comment: Just checking. What does `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc` show?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc` shows `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 10 22:28 /usr/bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc`

Comment: Keep following the link :-)  I'm guessing `/etc/alternatives/gcc` is a script that invokes the real gcc with -E. That's a non-standard installation you have there (at least not one I have come across). Normally `/usr/bin/gcc` is just a link to the actual version of gcc to be used `/usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.8` for example on my system.

Comment: `ls -l /etc/alternatives/gcc` gives  `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Dec 10 22:29 /etc/alternatives/gcc -> /usr/bin/cpp-4.7`

Comment: Well there you go. It's linked to the preprocessor. Which is what `-E` essentially means - dump the preprocessed output. From here I think Stackoverflow's job is done. You'll have to work out for yourself why your installation is set up in such a strange way.

Comment: Thanks for that everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is revealed in the verbose compiler output:

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' [...]

-E provokes GCC just to preprocess the input, so the resulting 'test' file actually is the input file with the single include resolved (recursively).

Since you did not add the -E parameter explicitely, gcc obviously did so implicitely. According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-05/msg00093.html) discussion on gcc.gnu.org, your version of gcc seems to have this compiled in, so I assume you would have to recompile gcc from fixed source code - or get a properly compiled gcc version from whichever source (Debian repositories?).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `\gcc` instead of `gcc`. The leading backslash tells the shell to ignore any aliases which might shadow the executable of the same name. You can also use the full gcc path to achieve the same.

You can also check there is no aliases or functions named gcc using `type gcc`, `whatis gcc` or maybe `which gcc` or even using a lower level `set|grep gcc`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you work through the comments, you'll see that the problem was resolved — to the extent Stack Overflow can resolve it — by deducing that there was a stray `-E` in the command line.  While I agree that if there was an alias for `gcc` that included `-E` then your technique would avoid the problem, there's evidence in the commentary that the problem is more fundamental than that.